# use python instead of django shell

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I have a basic project called airline with one app called flights. I create one model called Flight.

in a file called test.py I have:

```
from flights.models import Flight

f= Flight(origin="New York",destination="London", duration = 415)
f.save()
```

where do I place this file in order to run and update the database table? makemigrations and migrate were run successfully.  Is there anything else that needs to be done to make the code run?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). This is a migration you make yourself, for example to add/update/remove data.

You do this by first constructing a migration file with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty flights
```

next in the migration file, you can define a function to run and to create the `Flight` object:

```
from django.db import migrations

def add_flight(apps, schema_editor):
    Flight = apps.get_model('flights', 'Flight')
    Flight.objects.create(origin='New York', destination='London', duration=415)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('flights', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_flight),
    ]
```

We load the class with `apps.get_model('flights', 'Flight')`. This will construct a Django model of the `Flight` at *that* moment of the migrations. If for example you later add an extra field to your `Flight` then, as long as that migration did not run, the `Flight` will not have that extra field.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question.  I created the model in models.py, ran makemigrations and then ran migrate.  Having done that within the django framework I now want to add a record to the database

Comment: @DCR: yes. This is exactly what you can do. Since you create an extra migration, but not to change the database *structure*, but to add/update/remove data. This is what a *data migration* is used for. Django will thus inspect the database, see that it did not run this data migration, run it, and thus add the record to the table.

Comment: Wow, this seems really convoluted.  I'm looking for a way to add many (like 100,000) records to the database.  Also, how do you load the class. I have the file 0002_auto_20201121_1951.py with the code as shown but what do I do with it?

Comment: @DCR: you run migrations. Django will see that a migration did not run, run it, and thus create the records.

Comment: @DCR: for a large amount of records, you can use `bulk_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk_create

Comment: I'm sorry, but again this isn't going to work. If you are building a website and a user inputs data how do you get the data into the database?  You need to be able to get the dat into the database running python code and not have to hire somebody to run migrations every time someone enters data!

Comment: @DCR: well normally you each time run migrations when you deploy new code. The idea is that you use data migrations to make data more "portable", such that it will also create the same data on the production server, test server, etc. You do not need to run this manually, normally one runs this with a management tool like Heroku: https://help.heroku.com/GDQ74SU2/django-migrations

Comment: OMG. heroku is even more convoluted then django! So, do you just add the records using python sql commands?sql